# CombineBy Key Spark Method

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

This code below is supposed to find Per-Key Average using combineByKey():

```
val result = input.combineByKey(
(v) => (v, 1),
(acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
(acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)).
map{ case (key, value) => (key, value._1 / value._2.toFloat) }  
result.collectAsMap().map(println(_))
```

I am confused on the execution of the method above. Let's assume we have the data set
`( (1,1), (1,3), (2,4), (2,3), (3,1) )`.

**So the execution of combineByKey will look something like this?:**

1) First it will create an accumulator with `(1,1)`.
2) Then when it encounters a tuple with the same key (1) it will add the key values together? So when it encounters `(1,3)` the new accumulator for the key 1 will look like `(2,2)`. Since it added the keys of `(1,1) and (1,3)` and since there are two tuples with the key 1 it will put a 2 (on the right side) in `(2,2)`.
3) Then it will continue doing this for all the same keys.
4) Then in the end it will take all of the accumulators from each of the partitions and add the keys (left hand side of the tuple) and the number of times it occurred (right hand side of the tuple) into one tuple for each key.

Sorry if this is a little off, I am still getting used to the functional programming methods!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, a lot of clarity can be derived from looking at the types for the method and containing class.

`PairRDDFunctions[K, V]`

`def combineByKey[C](
createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C, 
mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C, 
mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]`

We have a class with 2 type params, a Key and a Value, and a method with one more, a combiner.

You are asked to provide functions to

- turn a Value into a Combiner
- turn a Value and a Combiner into a Combiner
- turn a Combiner and a Combiner into a Combiner

Immediately, this makes your description, of adding keys together, impossible since we haven't provided any methods that operate on Keys.

For each key:

1. First it will create Combiner from a Value, in this case by putting the value into the first slot of a tuple2 with a 1 in the second slot `(1, 1)`.
2. Then it will merge each additional Value for the same key into the Combiner by adding the value to the first slot of the tuple2 and incrementing the second slot. (1 + 3, 1 + 1) == (4, 2)
3. Then it will continue doing this for all the entries for the same key.
4. Then in the end it will take all of the accumulators from each of the partitions and add the Values (left hand side of the tuple) and the number of times it occurred (right hand side of the tuple) into one tuple for each key.

Your confusion may stem from the fact that your key and value are of the same type. Your code would compile if you changed the keys to `Strings`, but not if you did that with the Values.

Comment: Ohh you pointed out exactly what was confusing me, the fact that both the key and value were numbers! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, it makes sense now!

Comment: Also just to clarify at the very end when it "takes all of the accumulators from each of the partitions and add the Values (left hand side of the tuple) and the number of times it occurred (right hand side of the tuple) into one tuple for each key". It knows which key each key value pair belongs to from the different partitions. So let's say from partition 1 and 2 get (5,4) and (3,2) for key 1 respectively. And (3,4) and (4,5) for key 2 respectively. So spark will know to group the key 1 tuples together and the key 2 tuples together?

Comment: Yes, the structure you have is basically `(key: Int, (sum: Int , count; Int ))`

Comment: Got it! Thanks for clarifying!